# Mist Wallet Contracts are stuck

Tags: mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I synced my blockchain using Ethereum Mist, created an account and tried to create a single wallet contract.

Once I made the wallet the contact creation transaction went through, however the wallet in Mist is now stuck at "*Creating...*". I tried importing the same wallet and I ended with another entity stuck at "*Importing...*"

[image]